# Is it possible to exclude logs from coverage in sbt project?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, code-coverage

I have an sbt project with `sbt-scoverage` library. I want to know that there is some possibility to not count logs in coverage report.

I checked the `sbt-scoverage` [ScoverageKeys](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/blob/master/src/main/scala/scoverage/ScoverageKeys.scala), but I found only options to disable packages or files. I'm not interested in using:

```
// $COVERAGE-OFF$
...
// $COVERAGE-ON$
```

Sometimes it's annoying when you want to achieve some coverage and files that contains logs are not covered in 100% based on the report.

Any hints very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible:

`-P:scoverage:excludedPackages:.*\.utils\..*;.*\.SomeClass;org\.apache\..*`

See [github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin#excluding-code-from-coverage-stats)

In `build.sbt` define:

```
coverageExcludedPackages := ".*\\.Reverse.*;views.*;adapters.*;controllers.*;.*\\.javascript.*"
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `excludedPackages` will work. I thought it only affects packages