# how to ignore log statements in scoverage

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage, scoverage

i am using [sbt-scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage) plugin for code coverage I am getting a very low code coverage of 21%, in codeCoverage report i can see red lines on all the log statements i have used in my classes how can i ignore that
I have tried the solution given here as i am having the same prolem
[Is it possible to exclude logs from coverage in sbt project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107013/is-it-possible-to-exclude-logs-from-coverage-in-sbt-project)

i have added this line in my build.sbt

```
coverageExcludedPackages := ".*\\.Reverse.*;org.slf4j.*"
```

it's not working I can still see the red color covering the log statement inside my code
[image]

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think what `scoverage` is trying to tell you is that you don't have tests covering those branches. If it "ignores" logging, it would still complain about the `Resume`s not being hit. This would increase the code coverage number, but not the information you get out of `scoverage`. If those branches are important, you might want to add a test that triggers an exception and observes the result. If they are not, then the low coverage number is probably not important.

Comment: If you have branches that are only guards/logging against assertion errors ("it should never happen, but now that it happened we want to know why"), so testing them would be hard/pointless, you can exclude them from coverage by surrounding them with `// $COVERAGE-OFF$Optional message` and `// $COVERAGE-ON$`.